# Why does this for loop not recognise indicies as int, float, string or boolean?

Tags: python, list, loops

Here is a short piece of code which is meant to check what data type a certain variable is, the return says `True`, followed by `False`, `False`, `False`. Could somebody tell me what is wrong with this code and how I could do a process such as this more efficiently?

```
examples = [100, 1.45, "Bob", True]
types = [int, float, str, bool]

for x in range(0, 3):
    if type(examples[x]) == type(types[x]):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Comment: Actually it prints False, False, False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compare the type with the word in the list and not it's type. 
Also note that [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) excludes the second argument, and hence you need to do `range(0,4)` or `range(4)` which is better.

```
for x in range(0, 4):
    if type(examples[x]) == (types[x]):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

A better way is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

You can change your code as,

```
for x in range(0, 4):
    if isinstance(examples[x],types[x]):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

As `isinstance` returns a boolean value, you can directly do

```
for x in range(0, 4):
    print(isinstance(examples[x],types[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements of `types` are classes (types) and `type` returns `type` for each of those. There're no types in `examples`, thus `type(examples[x]) == type` will always evaluate to `False`.

This should work:

```
for x in range(4):
    if type(examples[x]) == types[x]: # <- remove type(...)
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

You could also do this using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
In [3]: for x in map(isinstance, examples, types):
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do `type(types[x])`.  `types` already contains types.  If you take the type of a type, you get `type`.

Just do `if type(examples[x]) == types[x]`.

Even better is to do it this way:

```
for example, typ in zip(examples, types):
    if type(example) == typ:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

This has the added advantage of comparing all the types in the list, not just the first 3.

Why you want to do this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

to fix:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    if type(examples[x]) == types[x]: # you were type(instance of type) => type 
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

for improvement:

```
for x in range(0, 4): # did you miss the last element?
    print isinstance(examples[x],types[x]) # refer to link
```

[link : learn about isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)